# PayPal API call daily limit

Tags: api, paypal, limit

Does anyone know how many API calls PayPal allow each day? I'm using GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails to check if payment has been successfully made and I might be doing the API call a lot of times each day. They have the error code on their docs but didn't specify the rate limit.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be addressed to PayPal support.

Comment: PayPal uses SO as their support forum and they lead people here.   I'm not sure how how the SO sponsorship works, but if they don't like what PayPal is doing they need to not allow them to use this as a sponsored forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never run into any daily limit issues with API calls.  That said, I try to avoid hitting the API that many times.

I would recommend you take a look at [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/).  It will automatically POST details about transactions to a URL listener you have on your server.  That script that receive the data and update your system accordingly.  This happens in real-time so everything would update automatically and immediately.  This way you don't have to hit the API to pull details because IPN will feed those details as they happen.

Comment: Thank you. I will be taking on their IPN.